# Do games for the Sony Xperia need to be ported?

Tags: psp

Or can it run PSPs game as they were originally released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need to be ported.  The official line is that the PSP Xperia is a "Playstation Phone" and not a "Playstation Portable".  Seems like a bit of a letdown if you ask me.  Here is a quote:

> "[Xperia Play owners] will have to repurchase the games, so it's not totally integrated. I think the exciting thing is that there are games which people are very, very aware of."